# Go plugin debugging

Tags: go, plugins, delve

There is a golang application that loads the plugin at runtime. I am developing this plugin and I would like to ask if there is an opportunity to debug the code of my plugin?

I tried to run delve by compiling both the application and the plugin with `--gcflags="all=-N -l"`, but running the application in the debugger I got an error `the executable file does not contain debugging information for the plugin`

Are there ways to debug golang plugin?

Comment: _"the executable file does not contain debugging information for the plugin"_ that's because plugins are not compiled / bundled into the executable binary. That's the whole point of Go plugins. If you want to debug it, call it directly and not as a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: put breakpoint via [`runtime.Breakpoint()`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Breakpoint), then run application with delve. It will stop on breakpoint at the plugin code.

Don't forget to build plugin and application with flags: `go build -trimpath -gcflags "all=-N -l"`

Answer (score 0):

It released a [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/23495-dlvx) to resolve this solution.

Here is the [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOK-5DCDVNY)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).